# How to add plugin for iOS into Phonegap via CLI?

Tags: cordova, phonegap, phonegap-cli

I'm trying to build my app using the **Phonegap CLI**. I've got the project created, and then when I try and add the plugins I get:

> $ sudo phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
>
> Error: Failed to fetch plugin
>   git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git via
>   registry.
>
> Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is
>   incorrect.
>
> Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
>
> Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>
> npm ERR! code 1
>
> npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q
>   https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git
>   /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4dc164cf
>
> npm ERR! /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4dc164cf/.git:
>   Permission denied
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!
>   /Users/apple/.npm/_logs/2018-03-02T11_53_27_023Z-debug.log

The full log has this in it:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git',
1 verbose cli   '--production',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose npm-session 85b442bcb6c2c486
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git Command failed: $
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4dc164cf/.git: Permission denied
8 verbose stack Error: Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.gi$
8 verbose stack /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4dc164cf/.git: Permission denied
8 verbose stack
8 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
8 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
8 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
8 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)

8 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)

9 verbose cwd /Users/apple/Desktop/chambes phonegap app/Chamresdhotesapp

10 verbose Darwin 17.4.0

11 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "git+https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-glo$
12 verbose node v8.9.4
13 verbose npm  v5.6.0
14 error code 1
15 error Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization.git /Users/apple$
15 error /Users/apple/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4dc164cf/.git: Permission denied
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If I browse to  **/Users/apple/**, I don't see a **.npm** folder. Is this hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Eugh, I'm kicking myself!!!!

- My project folder was called "chambres new test". It didn't seem to like the spaces. I've re-created it as just "chambres", and it adds plugins now
- I was trying to add plugins like so:

sudo phonegap plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device.git

For some reason it didn't like that. It did however work with:

```
sudo phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-device
```